# Collections.reverse() vs Lists.reverse() which one is faster?

Tags: java, guava

I am interested in following question: Collections.reverse() vs Lists.reverse() which one is faster?

Comment: You have to have the algorithm or be given the time complexity to know this

Comment: It's too bad the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html) [code](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java) isn't available for these classes, or you could look it up and find out exactly how they work.

Comment: @jgr208: Or you could... profile them.

Comment: @ColinDeClue but what if it will be an unknown input? profiling will never replace algorithms and time complexity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They do different things.

`Collections.reverse` takes a mutable list and reverses its order.  It takes linear time.  It has to.

Guava's `Lists.reverse` returns a *view* of the list that is reversed.  It returns in constant time, but you'll pay the (small) overhead of the view for each operation.